Cannot remove locale kubuntu
I've been learning russian recently, as such i tried to add to kubuntu the russian language under regional settings --> Language. And as an additional keyboard layout.
I then started to notice various console commands would output themself in russian, ksnip was in russian etc. While this may sound like a good way to expand vocabulary, it's inconvenient for work.
I then tried to remove the language again under the aforementioned settings area, however everytime i do the apply button remains greyed out, and when i click off that setting area and back onto it again, the locale has been re-added to the list. I've tried rebooting to see if that would make the chance sync, but i'm still getting russian language in applications. What's also odd, is how it's not ALL applications, just some. The system settings etc are all in english, as it kate email client firefox etc.
How can i set it back so all of this is in english and the russian translation for these programs is removed?

I don't use Kubuntu. KDE may do things differently than the standard Ubuntu's Gnome. Vanilla Ubuntu allows adding support for many languages (and different scripts and fonts if required by any given language) without changing the desktop language if that one is kept at the top of the list of langu8ages and/or regional settings.

That seems consistent here too. There is an order in this screen, and i made sure english was still at the top. I just mistakenly thought i needed to add the language for the keyboard and now want the language pack itself gone as it's targeting the wrong language pack and the wrong order.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/769609/how-to-install-additional-languages-in-kubuntu-16-04-lts

I have tried effectively doing that same process. However removing the language pack is not removing it, it just pops back again. Is there possibly a commandline option which will destroy it/a file i can edit? I am assuming this is a bug with the discover GUI resulting in it not actually performing the removal operation.

Perhaps you should start by removing the keyboard layout for the Cyrillic  keyboard you don't have?

Ah yeah that helped. It gave me and error of a mismatch in the language pack when i removed that keyboard. Which then offered me an alternate way to remove the main language pack where the apply button worked. I'll answer my own question with it. Thank you for your help :)

This is a bug with discover failing to update language packs when they are removed, only added-reordered. If anyone else ever suffers this issue the following steps corrected it for me, thanks to @ChanganAuto.

Remove the keyboard layout for keyboard you do not have.

Go back into regional and language settings, and delete the region pack you are not wanting your system to use/display in.

Change the order of any other languages you have on there/add a new language (in my case i swapped english US and english UK around).

Press Apply which should now be available.

Log out and back in again.


This should clean up the mis-targeted language packs. You can add the keyboard layout back again afterwards without any ill effects. I'm not sure why it blocks syncing of the regional pack, but hopefully this saves someone else any wasted time with the same issue. While mine was for russian, i would assume this would be the same process for any language pack.
